# Pointer and primitive type return different array members

Tags: c++

A few things.

1. When I declare my struct with a member array of size `3`, wouldn't that mean that array has 4 elements? 0, 1, 2, 3? Why them, when I try to insert the characters `A`, `B`, and `C`, it tells me `initializer-string for array of chars is too long [-fpermissive]`?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   struct Student {
       double no;
       char grade[3];
   };

   int main() {
       struct Student harry = {975, "ABC"};
   }
   ```
2. When I print the address of a specific index of a character array I get the following results from the following code:

   ```
   struct Student {
       double no;
       char grade[4];
   };

   int main() {

       struct Student harry = {975, "ABC"};

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           cout << "h.g[" << i << "]" << harry.grade[i] << endl;

       for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
           cout << "h.g[" << i << "]" << &harry.grade[i] << endl;
   }
   ```

Results:

```
h.g[0]A
h.g[1]B
h.g[2]C
h.g[3]
&h.g[0]ABC
&h.g[1]BC
&h.g[2]C
&h.g[3]
```

Why does the first index print `ABC`, and then `BC`, and so forth instead of each character separately like the first loop?

Comment: Size 3 means 3 elements. Pretty simple really. If it had 4 elements its size would be 4. "Size" does not mean "index of the last element" it means the size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, declaring an array like `T arr[3]` gives you an array with 3 elements, not 4. The 3 in the declaration is the size of the array. Indices start at 0, so the indices for the elements are 0, 1, and 2.

The string literal `"ABC"` gives you an "array of 4 `const char`" where the last element is the null character. Your program is ill-formed if you attempt to initialise an array with a string literal that has too many characters:

> There shall not be more initializers than there are array elements.

In the first loop you are getting each character of the array and printing it out. When you print a `char` you get only that `char` as output.

When you take the address of an element of the array, with `&harry.grade[i]`, you get a `char*`. When you output a `char*`, the I/O library treats it as a C-style null-terminated string. It will output from that character to the first null character it finds. That's why you get the character at position `i` and the characters following it.

Comment: @eveo I've just updated. Your code shouldn't have been compiling. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: g++, the second piece of code has `grade` initialized to 4 as opposed to the error generated in the first by 3 indices.

Answer (score 1):

> When I declare my struct with a member array of size 3, wouldn't that mean that array has 4 elements? 0, 1, 2, 3?

No, it means it has three elements, which you can access with indices 0,1,2.

> Why does the first index print ABC, and then BC, and so forth instead of each character separately like the first loop?

<strike>You are accessing beyond the bound of an array, which leads to **undefined behaviour**. That means anything could happen. You are also assigning a size-4 character array, `"ABC"`, to a size-3 array. So you have out of bonds read and write access.</strike>
The 4th element in char array "ABC" it the null-termination `\0`. When you print the address of any element of a `char[N]` with `std::cout`, it will see a `char*`, which it interprets as a null-terminated string. So it will print characters up to the null termination. So if you print from the beginning, you get `A, b, C`. If you print from the second element you get `B,C`, and so on.

Comment: The second question is not assuming the definition of `grade` from the first question. I declared the sizes differently.

Comment: @eveo sorry about that. I think I answered that question now.